# Disable previous dates in Odoo datepicker

Tags: datepicker, odoo, datetimepicker

I want to restrict the user selecting previous date from the date picker of odoo-8. Please give me how to disable previous dates in odoo datepicker

Comment: I had an idea to edit the JS file. But I m afraid it would affect the other default functionalities.

Comment: You may take a copy of that JS file and store it safe place. Apply your logic on it, check it weather other functionality affected or not.

Comment: the only way i've been able to do this, is to raise an error message whenever the user tries to submit the form with a date that's less than the previous date....would you be ok with that?

Comment: Yeah sure. Would you please share the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a module for that https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_widget_datepicker_options/

If you have a date field named current_date

```
<field name="current_date" />
```

After installing the module, just add the option for the jquery datepicker `minDate` and set it to 0 like this

```
<field name="current_date" options="{'datepicker':{'minDate': 0}}"/>
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

I previously did this by
setting an onchange on the field that'll be triggered every time the field is changed, and in the onchange you can convert the date to a python date (with odoo's default time format) and compare it to the current date

```
from datetime import datetime
from openerp import api
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT
from openerp.exceptions import Warning

@api.onchange('current_date')
def onchange_date(self):
    if datetime.strptime(self.current_date, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT).date() < datetime.now().date():
        raise warning('Please select a date equal/or greater than the current date')
        return False
    return my_date
```

Comment: also looking at the module code at the backend, it's very straightfoward it's just javascript that maps the value from the options attribute in the xml view straight to the jquery datepicker

Comment: It really helped me. Thanks a lot @danidee.

Comment: Hello, i have same problem in backend. How to disable in min date? /not web/

Comment: The `onchange` code I posted should work in the backend (It's `python` code)