# How to disable days after current date in odoo datepicker?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a view with a date field. The user must not select a date after today. How can I disable all days after the current date in Odoo datepicker?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581583/disable-previous-dates-in-odoo-datepicker]
I think this post will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date picker `maxDate` is used to set the maximum selectable date which will disable days after the current date.

I did not find a way to pass the current date dynamically from XML, so I overrode `fields_view_get` to change `options` attribute and set the `maxDate` to the current date.

The following example set the maxDate option to the `date_invoice`:

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    @api.model
    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        res = super(AccountInvoice, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
        if view_type == 'form':
            doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
            for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='date_invoice']"):
                node.set('options', "{'datepicker': {'maxDate': '%sT23:59:59'}}" % fields.Date.today().strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT))
            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
        return res
```

**Edit:**

You can use `or` inside the XPATH expression to specify the second field name.

```
doc.xpath("//field[@name='date_invoice' or @name='date_due']")
```

***Edit:***

Try to specify a time at `23:59:59`

```
node.set('options', "{'datepicker': {'maxDate': '%sT23:59:59'}}" % fields.Date.today().strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT))
```

Comment: What if a need to do the same with two date fields on the same  view? Should I just add an extra "for loop"?

for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='other_date']"):
                node.set('options', "{'datepicker': {'maxDate': '%s'}}" % fields.Date.today().strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT))
            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)

Comment: I have found a bug, when I open the form for the firs time and I try to select the current date (date). I cannot do it, although the day is enabled. I have to select other date, and then, select the current date, Have you  get the same bug?

Comment: I think it chooses midnight on the current date, that means you can't select time during the current day and this is why it is excluded.

Comment: When I add  {'maxDate': '%sT23:59:59'} I can select the current date for the first time, but after selecting the current date I can also select the day after today (I dont want that) This is the behaviour: When I open the datepicker, the day after today is disabled, but when I select other date, the 'day after today' is suddely enabled

Comment: I checked the option and it works as expected. I could not reproduce your issue, it seems like there is another code that alters the `maxDate` option.